# Troubles creating a proper lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

This is the code I need to alter:

```
var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), typeof(E).Name);
MemberExpression leftExpr = MemberExpression.Property(xParam, this._KeyProperty);
Expression rightExpr = Expression.Constant(id);
BinaryExpression binaryExpr = MemberExpression.Equal(leftExpr, rightExpr);
//Create Lambda Expression for the selection
Expression<Func<E, bool>> lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(binaryExpr, new ParameterExpression[] { xParam });
```

Right now the expression I'm getting out of this is `(x => x.RowId == id)` and what I want to change it to is `(x => x.RowId)` so that I can use it in an `OrderBy` for the `ObjectContext.CreateQuery(T)` method called later on.

Does anyone know how to change the above code so the lambda is correct to use in an OrderBy to order by the ID field?

**Side Notes:** The RowId is coming from this._KeyProperty I believe. This is part of a generic repository using the entity framework on Asp.Net MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit creating the constant and "=":

```
  var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "x");
  var propertyAccessExpr = Expression.Property(xParam, this._KeyProperty);
  var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(propertyAccessExpr, xParam);
```

This assumes that _KeyProperty has type 'bool'.  If it has a different type, just change Func<E, bool> to the appropriate type.

(**Edited** to incorporate asgerhallas and LukLed's good suggestions)

Comment: I believe it should be a Func<E, int> or something like that then.

Comment: I think that you can change var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(propertyAccessExpr, new ParameterExpression[] { xParam }) to var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(propertyAccessExpr, xParam); You don't have to create ParameterExpression array.

Comment: @LukLed You are correct.  The original code had the "new ParameterExpression[]" and I just left it.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks.